# Understanding chrome.storage.sync's behaviour when not signed in to the Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I've been playing around with the [`chrome.storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API as part of a Google Chrome extension that I'm building.

The API makes it clear that if you sign in to the Chrome browser with your Google account and use `chrome.storage.sync.set` then all the data that is set will be accessible next time you sign in to a Chrome browser with the same Google account and use `chrome.storage.sync.get`.

What the API doesn't make particularly clear is how `chrome.storage.sync` behaves *when not signed in to the Chrome browser.*

From my experiments it appears that, when *not* signed in to the Chrome browser, `chrome.storage.sync.set` and `chrome.storage.local.set` save to different places.

It says in the API:

> When Chrome is offline, Chrome stores the data locally. The next time
>   the browser is online, Chrome syncs the data. Even if a user disables
>   syncing, storage.sync will still work. In this case, it will behave
>   identically to storage.local.

It appears that the place where

> Chrome stores the [synced] data locally

is different to where `chrome.storage.local.set` stores it. Can anyone confirm if this is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Chrome.storage.sync is unable to connect to the internet, it stores data in a new, temporary place locally. It does not store it in Chrome.storage.local and is still accessed through Chrome.storage.sync.

The confusion seems to be in the language. Chrome.storage.local is a separate location, and Chrome.storage.sync will behave LIKE Chrome.storage.local. It does not use the same storage location

Comment: 'When Chrome.storage.sync is unable to connect to the internet, it stores data in a new, temporary place locally.' Is this also true when someone IS connected to the Internet, but isn't signed in to the Chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

Actually chrome description has clearly stated on https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

> When Chrome is offline, Chrome stores the data locally. The next time
>   the browser is online, Chrome syncs the data. Even if a user disables
>   syncing, storage.sync will still work. In this case, it will behave
>   identically to storage.local.